# Multiple relationships as the inverse of a single relationship?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, data-modeling

I am storing media in my app. Sometimes, I'll have audio and text which corrolate, and sometimes I'll have an audio file. I've decided to create two entities. I'll have my "MediaItem" and "CombinedItem".

On my CombinedItem, I've set three one-to-one relationships. On my MediaItem, I can only have a single inverse relationship. The question is, how do I set that up?

Here's what my items look like:

[image]

Am I doing it wrong? Should I just have a single media item with several properties for"isVideoFavorite", "isTextFavorite", "isAudioFavorite"?  I feel like I'm following the database model too closely, but I'm not sure I have a choice here. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the core-data way of handling this is to create a different entity for your different mediaItems. MediaItem is the parent entity of those three.

[image]

Comment: Wait, how do I attach the mediaItem to each of the AudioItem, TextItem and VideoItem entities? A relationship? How do I set the inverse on the mediaItem?